# Deploy a sharepoint 2010 timer job solution with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We made a solution containing a custom timer job that needs to be deployed on a server with sharepoint 2010 but without visual studio 2010.

How can this be done ?
I haven't find anything regarding this issue.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

first thing find it out your feature scope of Timer job executed. you should install and deployed your `WSP` of solution using `SharePoint Management Shell`.

go to :

> Start > All Programs > Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products > SharePoint 2010 Management Shell

open it and

#### Add Solution:

> Add-SPSolution c:\wspfilename.wsp

#### Deploy/Install Solution:

> Install-SPSolution –Identity wspfilename.wsp –WebApplication http://contoso.com -GACDeployment

afterward you can activated feature manually or using Management Shell like [here](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/mark-digiovanni/discovering-activating-and-deactivating-features-sharepoint-site-collection-usi)

Hops it helps!!

Comment: Just to point out that a Timer Job cannot be created in a feature at site collection level activating it via web on site collection features. This operation will raise a "Permission denied" error even if you do it with the farm administrator. It must be done through the management shell, with `Get-SPFeature` and `Enable-SPFeature`.